# timestamp missing in log(JAVA)

Tags: java, spring, maven, slf4j, lombok

Totally a newbie to the concept I am asking about.

I have a maven projet, with the support of project lombok and Slf4j for logging.
I expect the timestamp to be present in the log output. But I observe only the class name and the message.

Could anyone guide me through or suggest some links to go to?

1. pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

2. Main class:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class ObjectsAndVariables {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           log.info("HELLO");

}}
```

3. In the src/main/resources there is  logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <conversionRule conversionWord="clr"
        converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wex"
        converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wEx"
        converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
        value="${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}" />

    <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <!-- Console output log level -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

4. Output:

```
[main] INFO model.ObjectsAndVariables - HELLO
```

How to get the timestamps? Is there anything wrong in the heirarchy?

Comment: This output is from `slf4j-simple`, you don't use logback currently. You'd need to remove the afore mentioned dependency, then add logback *and* the logback-to-slf4j bridge dependencies. Also see this great tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/logback

Comment: Hi Lino, thank you for your response. On the removal of  ```slf4j-simple```, and adding the logback and the logback to slf4j dependencies, I get errors :

Comment: ```SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions prior to 1.8.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/C:/Users/R.Premsagar/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you posted in the comment I think your problem is version incompatibility I did a test with the following dependencies and your `logback.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0-alpha9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-alpha4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0-alpha9</version>
</dependency>
```

I get following log for my class:

```
2021-08-17 13:22:05.773  INFO   --- [           main] c.h.s.ch4.SystemCommandApplication       : HELLO
```

as you can see it is compatible with your logback configuration